# Renaming file in jar via Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I have a jar task (well a ShadowJar, but that shouldn't matter I think).

```kotlin
named<com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar>("shadowJar") {
        archiveClassifier.set("")
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

There's a file called `linux/x64/org/lwjgl/liblwjgl.so` within a dependency which I need to rename to `liblwjgl3.so`. Is there a way to do that within the jar task?

Comment: I deleted my answer because using `rename` doesn't seem to work. Instead of passing the names of the JAR entries from each dependency to the transformer, it passes the JAR file itself. The plugin you're using seems to have [its own transformer API](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/merging/) (which is a different interface from the Gradle one). That may be able to do what you want; though to be honest, I don't really understand how to implement the interface.